# Advanced django queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have three models: a company, an asset, and a user. Each company has many assets (ForeignKey), and each asset has a single user (ForeignKey, since a user may own more than one asset).

I want to run a query that returns a list of companies in which a given user owns assets, and the number of assets that they own in each company.

I have tried doing this in python, like this:

```
companies = Company.objects.filter(asset__owner=self.request.user)
context['investments'] = [(x, Asset.objects.filter(company=x, owner=self.request.user).count()) for x in companies]
```

Perhaps unsurprisingly, this is incredibly slow, since a company can have 100,000 assets. It seemed that this would be better done at the database level, which led me to look at annotation and aggregation, but I couldn't get anywhere. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: It would be helpful if you add your relevant models here.

Comment: A very good article about django performance https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2016/02/21/building-high-performance-django-systems/. Also look the django documentation about prefetch_related and select_related querysets https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/2.1/ref/models/querysets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do annotate with condition:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, IntegerField

qs = Company.objects.filter(asset__owner=self.request.user)
qs = qs.objects.annotate(
    num_assets=Count(Case(
        When(asset__owner=self.request.user, then=1),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
)
```

read the docs [conditional-aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation)

Comment: Thank you! Could you have a look at the answer MichaelRoberts just posted? Is there something wrong with it? It seems to work, but what you've posted is more like what I expected.

Comment: @Alex This looks like it would be more efficient ... see if you can run some performance tests to see which would work quicker!

Comment: as i can see in your answer will count all assets include other users.

Comment: @BearBrown Well, that's what I would expect, but it doesn't, it seems to work

Comment: @Alex - are you sure you have more than one user in your database if you're in pre-production? As crazy as that sounds - I have done this thinking it works fine, but adding in more than one user and your `Query` goes off slightly...

Comment: @MichaelRoberts I do have more than one user, and if I transfer an asset from one to the other, the count changes... I don't mean to be difficult, and I'm happy to have a working answer, but it would be good to understand why!

Comment: @Alex - it feels like what Bear has outlined is more than sufficient to work. it adds one every time the asset__owner is equal to the request user, it also outputs an IntegerField() which is exactly what you need to pass through the context. You could even add Bear's method to your Company model...completely up to you. It may even be working because you are logging out of one user to add an asset to your own user, and vice versa. Keep testing what you think works and if it doesn't break - then excellent.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by a combination of `.filter(..)` and `.annotate(..)`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Company.objects.filter(
    asset__owner=some_user
).annotate(
    num_assets=Count('asset')
)
```

So here we return a `QuerySet` that contains `Company` objects, and every object has an extra attribute: `num_assets` that contains the number of assets owned by the given user in that `Company`.

Since here - given I understood it correctly - an asset always belongs to a *single company*, there is no *double counting*: in case it was a many-to-many relation, an assed owned by a user that belongs to two companies, would have incremented the count of both companies.

The queryset will therefore *only* return companies in which the user *has* assets, `Company`s without any assets owned by the user, are thus filtered out.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, each asset belongs to a single company. I looked at the above, but assumed that this would give me:
(as desired) the list of companies that contain at least one asset owned by the user, but that the annotation would give the total number of assets that that company owns (whether they are owned by the user or not)...

Comment: This worked for me as well within a quick app bed. All answers seem to work fine @Alex